# How to get Clojure Compojure app to run headless via compiled jar within Docker container?

Tags: clojure, docker, compojure, dockerfile

**Update**: this question has changed since the original set of commenters left responses. Apologies for any confusion.

---

This is my code repository https://github.com/Integralist/spurious-clojure-example you can use it as an example for what I'm working with.

> Note that the above repo relies on a library I've not yet published to Clojars (as I'm still testing it - hence this question opened). You can see the source code of the library here: https://github.com/Integralist/spurious-clojure-aws-sdk-helper

I have a "hello world" Clojure web app written with Compojure that I have working fine when run using `lein ring server` and `lein run` (as I have a `-main` function now created). It also runs to a certain extent when compiled down into a jar and I run `java -jar app.jar`.

My problem now is that if I try to run the default `java -jar app.jar` from within a Docker container I get the following error telling me...

```
spurious-clojure-example is starting
2015-02-14 00:58:03.812:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2015-02-14 00:58:03.854:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Started server on port 8080
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
```

My code is currently using a `-main` function like so...

```
(ns spurious-clojure-example.repl
  (:use spurious-clojure-example.handler
        ring.server.standalone
        [ring.middleware file-info file])
  (:gen-class))

(defonce server (atom nil))

(defn get-handler []
  (-> #'app
    (wrap-file "resources")
    (wrap-file-info)))

(defn start-server
  "used for starting the server in development mode from REPL"
  [& [port]]
  (let [port (if port (Integer/parseInt port) 8080)]
    (reset! server
            (serve (get-handler)
                   {:port port
                    :init init
                    :auto-reload? true
                    :destroy destroy
                    :join true}))
    (println (str "You can view the site at http://localhost:" port))))

(defn stop-server []
  (.stop @server)
  (reset! server nil))

(defn -main []
  (start-server))
```

...but how do I get the server to start headless? I can't quite follow the Compojure boilerplate code to decipher where or how it knows when to run headlessly or via browser?

I know that on the command line you can do `lein ring server-headless` so what's the programmatic equivalent of that?

Comment: Please add the contents of your `project.clj`. Especially the section for `:ring` and profiles are of interest.

Comment: @schaueho here is the `project.clj` https://github.com/Integralist/spurious-clojure-example/blob/master/project.clj (also inlined above)

Comment: A side note, but IMO it would be better to use 2 containers. One to build the application and another one to host it. In the hosting container you just have the JRE and the uber jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ring-server is primarily meant for development, it tries to open a browser when the server starts. This fails with a `java.awt.HeadlessException` on platforms without a GUI. You'll want to set the `:open-browser?` option to false to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [offical Docker docs on EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose)

> The EXPOSE instructions informs Docker that the container will listen
>   on the specified network ports at **runtime**. Docker uses this
>   information to interconnect containers using links (see the Docker
>   User Guide) and to determine which ports to expose to the host when
>   using the -P flag. Note: EXPOSE doesn't define which ports can be
>   exposed to the host or make ports accessible from the host by default.
>   **To expose ports to the host, at runtime, use the -p flag or the -P flag**.

So if you're setting the ring server port manually in your `project.clj`, ensure that you're using the same port also in your Dockerfile and then provide a mapping via -p or -P when starting docker.

I can't say for sure but I believe that your headless error message doesn't contribute to your problem.

Comment: OK, so it seems I just needed to add the `-p` flag as suggested rather than have the name in my Dockerfile. I was then able to access the compojure page in my browser. So I'm going to update my question to reflect that and so it leaves the main question being effectively: "how to package a clojure compojure app so that when the jar is run it doesn't drop you into a repl"